# W3C Geolocation speed specification

Tags: html, geolocation, gps, w3c, w3c-geolocation

In the Geolocation API spec, the W3C specified the speed property of the coordinates interface as

> The **speed** attribute denotes the magnitude of the horizontal component
>   of the hosting device's current velocity and is specified in meters
>   per second. If the implementation cannot provide speed information,
>   the value of this attribute must be null. Otherwise, the value of the
>   speed attribute must be a non-negative real number.

What is the reason behind only the horizontal component is being used? If a user were to move "vertically" (by this I assume along a line of longitude), would their speed be returned as zero?

I found [this changelog](http://www.w3.org/2008/geolocation/track/issues/99?changelog) and it appears the wording was changed from "ground speed" to "magnitude of horizontal component" in 2011. Is this implementation left up to the browsers?

Comment: I don't think vertically means along a line of longitude, I think it means perpendicular to the Earth's surface.  Otherwise your SatNav would report you as doing a lower speed the closer to North you were driving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

horicontaly means: moving on the ground in any direction (changes in latitude / longitude)

vertically means moving up into the air (changes in altitude)

further horicontal error therefore means error related to 2d position (lat +lon)
vertical error: eror in altitude.

Comment: This appears to be the most common sense interpretation. It's sort of an obvious conclusion but I just wanted to make sure it wasn't only incorporating one axis. Is "vertical" being perpendicular to the earth's surface a common geolocation phrasing?

Comment: Yes, Vertical is height. You can search for Vertical reference System in GEO Science. The World did more effort in norming horizontal System like UTM. Normation of vertical reference Systems is less advanced. On Some modern paper maps you can read about Vertical reference, too. So Trust me my answer is correct.

Comment: Bye the Way, when i Started with GPS Development , I too thought horizontal is longitude like x-axis. Later, After Some Time i found Out.

Comment: Bye the way, when I started with GPS Development, I too thought that horizontal is longitude like x-axis. Later, after some time i found out. This is a common missunderstanding.